# No rows rendered, no errors detected

Tags: reactjs

In my React component, trying to generate rows from the state. State object is being populated, but no rows is being rendered:

```
class DataTable extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.renderTableData = this.renderTableData.bind(this);
    this.fetchData = this.fetchData.bind(this);
    this.state = {
        Houses: []
    };
}
   
    


componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
   
}
renderTableData() {
   return( this.state.Houses.map((house, index) => {
        
            <tr key={index}>
                <td>{house.Id}</td>
                <td>{house.Country}</td>
                <td>{house.Address}</td>
                <td>{house.Description}</td>
                <td>{house.Photo}</td>
                <td>{house.Price}</td>
            </tr>
        
    }))
}
fetchData = () => {
    
    fetch('./AllHouses')
        .then(rsp => rsp.json())
        .then(allHouses => {
            this.setState({ Houses: allHouses });
           
        }).catch(
            function (error) { console.log(error.message); }
    );

    console.log(this.state.Houses);
}

render() {
    return (
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Country</th>
                    <th>Address</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Photo</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                **{this.renderTableData() }**
            </tbody>
        </table>
    );
}
}

ReactDOM.render(<DataTable />, document.getElementById('content'));
```

Comment: I'm expecting to see rows generated on the line {this.renderTableData() }

Comment: If you replace the line `{this.renderTableData() }` with `{JSON.Stringify(this.state.Houses)}`, what shows up?

Comment: add `return` before `<tr key={index}>` or wrap the tr with `()` instead of `{}`.      


   return this.state.Houses.map((house, index) => {
        return  <tr key={index}>
                <td>{house.Id}</td>
                <td>{house.Country}</td>
                <td>{house.Address}</td>
                <td>{house.Description}</td>
                <td>{house.Photo}</td>
                <td>{house.Price}</td>
            </tr>
        
    })

Comment: it should probably fix your issue

Comment: Thank you, but return provided by you did not change anything.

Comment: @LukeStorry your suggestion generates an error  - Text nodes cannot appear as a child of <tbody>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use the bind function but I recommend you use arrow functions directly.

You could call the array state.Houses on the jsx directly executing the map if you want, and then call the function renderTableData just like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class StackOverflow extends Component {
  state = {
    Houses: [],
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    // Data example
    this.setState({
      Houses: [
        {
          id: 1,
          Country: 'Country 1',
          Address: 'address 1',
          Description: 'Description 1',
          Photo: 'Photo 1',
          Price: 'Price 1',
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          Country: 'Country 2',
          Address: 'address 2',
          Description: 'Description 2',
          Photo: 'Photo 2',
          Price: 'Price 2',
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          Country: 'Country 3',
          Address: 'address 3',
          Description: 'Description 3',
          Photo: 'Photo 3',
          Price: 'Price 3',
        },
      ],
    });
  }

  renderTableData(house, index) {
    return (
      <tr key={index}>
        <td>{house.id}</td>
        <td>{house.Country}</td>
        <td>{house.Address}</td>
        <td>{house.Description}</td>
        <td>{house.Photo}</td>
        <td>{house.Price}</td>
      </tr>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Photo</th>
            <th>Price</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {this.state.Houses.map((house, index) =>
            this.renderTableData(house, index)
          )}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}

export default StackOverflow;
```

it's much better organized because only you have HTML code in the renderTableData, after if you want you can export that <tr .... /tr> on a different component and call it on that function.
It's going to be cleaner and reusable your code.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

add `return` before `<tr key={index}>` OR wrap the tr with `()` instead of `{}`.

```
renderTableData() {
 return this.state.Houses.map((house, index) => {
   return <tr key={index}>
            <td>{house.Id}</td>
            <td>{house.Country}</td>
            <td>{house.Address}</td>
            <td>{house.Description}</td>
            <td>{house.Photo}</td>
            <td>{house.Price}</td>
          </tr>
  })
}
```

Comment: No, still same issue - no rows returned

Comment: I added  console.log(this.state.Houses); as the next line after  renderTableData()  state has data.

Comment: If I'm initializing state like in your code sample it works fine - the problem with an API. outside of my call state is empty, inside of api call data is present

Comment: try changing this `fetchData = () =>` to `fetchData()` ,  OR remove bind for it inside the constructor.
if you are using arrow function approach, you don't need to use `.bind(this)` in constructor

Comment: also put a console log inside then where you are setting state in order to see what is the response of your api call, you can also check from network tab if you are getting the correct data from api call, make sure that your code is reaching this statement : `this.setState({ Houses: allHouses });` and also see if you have correct data there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221466/discussion-between-atif-saddique-and-yuri).